# How to create a Toggle?

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I want to create this "on click" function to have a toggle. By default, **body** has a"**margin: 0px;**", so I want a link to **Toggle** the Body's margin from 0px to 50px to the right. Animating the transition with a sliding effect would be nice!

A simple code I have...

```
   $("a").click(function () {
    $("body").css("margin","0px 0px 0px 50px");
    return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class in css then call jQuery [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
.someClass
{
 margin: 0 0 0 50px!important;
}

$("a").click(function () {
       $("body").toggleClass('someClass');
       return false;
 });
```

Comment: Using jquery though... I don't want to have problems with browsers if it's a css effect.

Comment: You can't animate jqueries toggleClass without using jqueryUi, here's the jqueryUi link: http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/ which has an additional parameter for the animation time. With plain jquery you can use .animate but that only works for inline styles, so there would be no 'easy' way to toggle, you would need to check the current margin value(.css('margin')) and then based on the conditional statement execute the different effect you want.